# Evaluate an expression with numerical values

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-value

I hope this time you guys can help me. I have the following numerical expression:

```
L = {L1, L3, L5}; 
CC = {CC2, CC4, CC6};

Gain = 1/(\[Sqrt]((CC2 Rin wn + CC4 Rin wn + CC6 Rin wn + (L1 wn)/Rout + (
       L3 wn)/Rout + (L5 wn)/Rout - CC2 CC4 L3 Rin wn^3 - 
       CC2 CC6 L3 Rin wn^3 - CC2 CC6 L5 Rin wn^3 - 
       CC4 CC6 L5 Rin wn^3 - (CC2 L1 L3 wn^3)/Rout - (CC2 L1 L5 wn^3)/
       Rout - (CC4 L1 L5 wn^3)/Rout - (CC4 L3 L5 wn^3)/Rout + 
       CC2 CC4 CC6 L3 L5 Rin wn^5 + (CC2 CC4 L1 L3 L5 wn^5)/
       Rout)^2 + (1 + Rin/Rout - CC2 L1 wn^2 - CC4 L1 wn^2 - 
       CC6 L1 wn^2 - CC4 L3 wn^2 - CC6 L3 wn^2 - CC6 L5 wn^2 - (
       CC2 L3 Rin wn^2)/Rout - (CC2 L5 Rin wn^2)/Rout - (
       CC4 L5 Rin wn^2)/Rout + CC2 CC4 L1 L3 wn^4 + 
       CC2 CC6 L1 L3 wn^4 + CC2 CC6 L1 L5 wn^4 + CC4 CC6 L1 L5 wn^4 + 
       CC4 CC6 L3 L5 wn^4 + (CC2 CC4 L3 L5 Rin wn^4)/Rout - 
       CC2 CC4 CC6 L1 L3 L5 wn^6)^2))
```

Now I want to replace L1, CC2, L3, etc. on the gain expression but I want to do it so that I write a vector like:

L={1,2,1}

and then replace {L1, L3, L5} -> {1,2,1}.

How can I do that? The goal of doing this is that the code is supposed to be adaptable for longer arrays, so doing it one by one is tedious.

Comment: Gain /. Thread[{L1, L3, L5} -> {1, 2, 1}]

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thank you! How can I use that to replace both L and C as well as the values of Rin and Rout, so multiple threads?

Comment: `Gain /. Flatten[{Thread /@ {L -> {1, 2, 1}, CC -> {3, 6, 2}}, Rin -> 7, Rout -> 9}]`